# Power series to evaluate a definite integral of $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^7}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, power-series

[image]

> Find a power series expansion of the function $f(x)=\dfrac1{1+x^7}$ about $x=0$. Use it to evaluate $\int_0^1 \dfrac1{1+x^7} dx$. Your answer should be expressed in the form of numerical series (a series, but not a power series).

So I have this question here. I found the power series representation which is:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{7n}$$

So I would be integrating:

$$\int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n x^{7n} \, dx$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \int_0^1 x^{7n} \, dx$$

Which I think is correct.

What does it mean by "You answer should be expressed in the form of a numerical series (a series, but not a power series)." though? Is there some closed form expression in which I have to represent the integral as?

Comment: $\int_0^1x^{7n}\;dx=\frac{1}{7n+1}$. I think that's all they're looking for.

Comment: Makes sense. I assume I also have to multiply that by the summation term in front of the integral? (Since it asks for an answer as a series)

Comment: Yes, so the end result is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{7n+1}$.

Comment: Yep. I just got that. Thanks a lot :) .

Answer (score 7):

Use the fact that the integral is a definite integral!
$$\int_0^1{}x^{7n}dx = \frac{1}{7n+1}$$

Therefore the summation then equals 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{7n+1}$$

Comment: Yep that's what I just got. Thanks :) .

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty: Note that the switch in integral and summation must be justified. It is in fact false in some cases.